# SVN 1.8.4 libserf-1.1.3.0.dylib

Tags: macos, svn, homebrew

After I updated SVN version on my mac using homebrew I'm getting following error:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libserf-1.1.3.0.dylib
    Referenced from: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/svn
    Reason: image not found
Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

I have no idea what libserf-1.1.3.0.dylib is and where it should be!

Any thought?

[**UPDATE 01**]
I tried installing serf using following:

```
brew install serf
```

and got the following error:

```
Error: No available formula for serf
```

also I checked svn dependncies on homebrew by doing `brew deps svn` there is no serf:

```
autoconf
automake
libtool
pkg-config
scons
sqlite
```

Comment: having the same issue after upgrading OS to mavericks, I wonder if it's related?

Comment: @Ericson578 It should be related, I had to compile svn 1.8.4 from source and now not xcode nor cornerstone are working! have to commit via terminal, hope someone find a solution

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Got it working.

If you want the latest svn uninstall and then build from source

```
brew remove svn
brew install --build-from-source svn
```

If you want an older version (I needed 1.6.17) then follow the direction [here](https://gist.github.com/gcatlin/1847248), but replace the line that says brew install with the install command from above (don't forget to remove svn first though)

Comment: This requires a C compiler installed on the machine.  And since my Mac doesn't have XCode, I cannot use this command...

Comment: @Igor, this solution is for users of the mac package manager homebrew. Homebrew requires the command line tools that come packaged with xcode. Regardless, unless you can find a binary for subversion you'll need some form of compiler or package manager to install subversion on your machine.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone has httpd installed with brew these commands worked for me:

```
brew unlink httpd
brew install svn
brew link httpd
```

Hope this helps!